# does anyone know tell me if this code is refactorable? And if so how?

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

```
    private void fillInvoiceListForName(String name, ArrayList<Invoice> mInvoices) {
    for (SupplierAccount account : listcontracts) {
        if (account.getSupplier() != null)
            if (account.getSupplier().equals(name)) {
                ArrayList<Contract> mContracts = account.getContracts();
                for (Contract contract : mContracts) {
                    mInvoices.addAll(contract.getInvoices());
                }
            }
    }
}

private void fillIncomeListForName(String name, ArrayList<Income> mIncomes) {
    for (SupplierAccount account : listcontracts) {
        if (account.getSupplier() != null)
            if (account.getSupplier().equals(name)) {
                ArrayList<Contract> mContracts = account.getContracts();
                for (Contract contract : mContracts) {
                    mIncomes.addAll(contract.getIncomes());
                }
            }
    }
}


private void fillDocumentListForName(String name, ArrayList<Document> mDocuments) {
    for (SupplierAccount account : listcontracts) {
        if (account.getSupplier() != null)
            if (account.getSupplier().equals(name)) {
                ArrayList<Contract> mContracts = account.getContracts();
                for (Contract contract : mContracts) {
                    mDocuments.addAll(contract.getDocuments());
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: just tip: parameter variables should start with p like pName or pInvoices not m. m stands for member. local variables like account should start with l like lAccount. Furthermore declare your local variable as final.

Comment: This type of question is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @StefanBeike I do not believe that to be a common java convention.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen yes but the code is a mixture of using that suffix. Either he used it all or nothing.

Comment: @StefanBeike Is it? As far as I can see, `m` stands for "multiple" or similar, it's used for collection types. And it's applied consistently. Apparently, there are other conventions, different from the one you are following.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: ok I dont know that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your methods have the iteration in common. What you want to do is abstract the iteration method while allowing the caller to specify an action to perform on the objects being iterated over. Essentially you want to combine an internal iterator (to perform the iteration) with a strategy (to perform the action).

With the Strategy pattern you can define different strategies which all have something in common, and then easily substitute one for the other. In this case, all of your methods collect information from a list of contracts and adds it to a list, though which information they collect varies.

#### Refactored method

```
private <E> void fillListForName(String name, List<? super E> listToFill, FillStrategy<E> fillStrategy) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be null");
    }
    for (SupplierAccount account : listContracts) {
        if (name.equals(account.getSupplier())) {
            List<Contract> contracts = account.getContracts();
            for (Contract contract : contracts) {
                fillStrategy.execute(listToFill, contract);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### The `FillStrategy` interface and an example implementation

```
interface FillStrategy<T> {
    public void execute(List<? super T> listToFill, Contract contract);
}

class InvoiceFillStrategy implements FillStrategy<Invoice> {
    @Override
    public void execute(List<? super Invoice> listToFill, Contract contract) {
        listToFill.addAll(contract.getInvoices());
    }   
}
```

#### Calling the refactored method

```
List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
InvoiceFillStrategy invoiceStrategy = new InvoiceFillStrategy();

System.out.println("Invoices for myCorp:");
fillListForName("myCorp", invoices, invoiceStrategy);
for (Invoice i : invoices) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

System.out.println("\nInvoices for otherCorp:");
invoices.clear();
fillListForName("otherCorp", invoices, invoiceStrategy);
for (Invoice i : invoices) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

#### Why?

The benefit of this approach is that you can create additional "strategies" without necessarily modifying any of the other classes involved. For example, you could create one that collects all invoices for sums over a given threshold:

```
class ExpensiveInvoiceFillStrategy implements FillStrategy<Invoice> {

    private int minimumAmount;

    public ExpensiveInvoiceFillStrategy(int minimumAmount) {
        this.minimumAmount = minimumAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(List<? super Invoice> listToFill, Contract contract) {
        for (Invoice invoice : contract.getInvoices()) {
            if (invoice.getAmount() >= minimumAmount) {
                listToFill.add(invoice);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just implementing this class and then calling `fillListForName` with an instance of it is enough - no change to `fillListForName` or `Contract` is necessary!

There are other ways to implement the iterator method and the strategies - some would even be considered "more pure" or "better" that what I've done here. I chose this approach because it kept the code similar to what you had, and because we're trying to solve a specific problem, not implement general support for internal iterators in Java (smarter guys are already working on that). Just be aware that it's not "perfect" :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it has powerful utilities for manipulating collections. For example, you could use [`FluentIterable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) in conjunction with `Predicate`s and `Function`s, to extract common logic, and use them to transform and filter your collections.

Below I have extracted common elements into the `filterAndTransform` method which allows you to pass in a `Function` so you can collect what you like from the `Contract` object:

```
private <T> List<T> filterAndTransform(String name, Function<Contract, Iterable<T>> function) {
    return FluentIterable.from(listcontracts)
        .filter(new HasSupplierPredicate())
        .filter(new SupplierNameMatchesPredicate(name))
        .transformAndConcat(new Function<SupplierAccount, Iterable<Contract>>() {
            @Override public Iterable<Contract> apply(final SupplierAccount account) {
                return account.getContracts();
            }
        })
        .transformAndConcat(function)
        .toList();
}

private void fillInvoiceListForName(String name, ArrayList<Invoice> mInvoices) {
    final Iterable<Invoice> invoices = filter(name, 
        new Function<Contract, Iterable<Invoice>>() {
            @Override public Iterable<Invoice> apply(final Contract contract) {
                return contract.getInvoices();
            }
    });
    mInvoices.addAll(invoices);
}

private void fillIncomeListForName(String name, ArrayList<Income> mIncomes) {
    final Iterable<Income> incomes = filter(name, 
        new Function<Contract, Iterable<Income>>() {
            @Override public Iterable<Income> apply(final Contract contract) {
                return contract.getIncomes();
            }
    });
    mIncomes.addAll(incomes);
}

// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an enum, and pass it as a parameter to a method:

```
public enum ContractValue {
    INVOICE, INCOME, DOCUMENT;
}

private void fillIncomeListForName(String name, ArrayList<Income> mIncomes, ContractValue contractValue) {
for (SupplierAccount account : listcontracts) {
    if (account.getSupplier() != null)
        if (account.getSupplier().equals(name)) {
            ArrayList<Contract> mContracts = account.getContracts();
            for (Contract contract : mContracts) {
                if (contractValue == ContractValue.INCOME) {
                     mIncomes.addAll(contract.getIncomes()); 
                } else if (contractValue == ContractValue.INVOICE) {
                     mInvoices.addAll(contract.getInvoices());
                } else if (contractValue == ContractValue.DOCUMENT) {
                     mDocuments.addAll(contract.getDocuments());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The enum can also have the action code, so you do not need the multi-if.

Comment: Plus, it should at least have been a `switch`.

Comment: I also thought that using a switch but your method mInvoices mDocument and must be provided as a parameter somewhere!